# Need help using 2 .js files

Tags: javascript

Both .js files work with my code separately, but when I try to access a constructor from one it does not work.

```
//.js file 1 Ex

(function(){


var Colors = function(color1,color2) {
this.color1 = color1;
this.color2 = color2;
};

})();
```

I need to use these in my second file as if they where in the first.

```
//.js file 2

var colors = [
    new Colors('green','blue'),
    new Colors('green','blue')];

    console.log(colors[1] + colors[2]);
```

Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(function(){


var Colors = function(color1,color2) {
this.color1 = color1;
this.color2 = color2;
};

})();
```

The point of the IIFE function wrapper here is to hide variables declared inside it. You can just take it off in this case. If your situation does require “private” variables like this, export the important parts globally somehow, e.g.

```
var Colors = (function() {
    function Colors(color1, color2) {
        this.color1 = color1;
        this.color2 = color2;
    }

    return Colors;
})();
```

Or

```
(function(global) {
    function Colors(color1, color2) {
        this.color1 = color1;
        this.color2 = color2;
    }

    global.Colors = Colors;
})(this);
```